# Podio webhook unverified

Tags: podio

I created an app a year ago and verified all needed webhooks.

December 14th 2016, some webhooks became unverified, despite of the fact that they were created and valided a year ago. I looked into Podio's status page, nothing happened that day.

I'm the only administrator of the target app and nothing changed since I created the app.

I wrote to support, but the given answer was not helpful.

Anyone had this weird issue or an explaination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hook might be un-validated if your service was too slow or down. Here is quote from https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks

> The hook must respond with a 2xx status code. If the status code is
>   different from 2xx more than 50 consecutive times the hook will return
>   to being unverified and will have to be verified again to be active.
>   Additionally, your hook may return to unverified if you do not send
>   responses in a timely manner. You should handle any heavy processing
>   asynchronously.